# Why the processMouseEvent method is not executed

Tags: java, swing

I created a class MyComponent that is just a yellow rectangle. I also overrided processMouseEvent to add mouse event for the component. My code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.*;

public class MyComponent extends JComponent{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame=new JFrame("Cua so");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        MyComponent myComponent;
        myComponent = new MyComponent();
        myComponent.setBounds(2, 2, 200, 40);
        frame.add(myComponent);
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation  (EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        }
    });
    System.out.println("<Main>");
}
    public MyComponent()
    {
        this.enableEvents(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
    }
    protected void ProcessMouseEvent(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("<Process mouse event>");
        switch(e.getID())
        {
            case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:
                System.out.println("<Mouse pressed>");
                break;
            case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED:
                System.out.println("<Mouse released>");
                break;
            case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED:
                System.out.println("<Mouse dragged>");
                break;
        }
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

and I don't know why the code in processMouseEvent is not executed. Could someone explain this, and I don't want to use addMouseListener
Thanks for reading!

Comment: try `processMouseEvent`,  not `ProcessMouseEvent` (no capital "P")

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it.